# How do I convert an integer to string in CakePHP?

Tags: string, cakephp, integer

In my CakePHP app when I try to get data like this:

```
    $this->loadModel('Radio');
    $posts = $this->Radio->find('all');
```

the integers are displayed like strings (in debug) :

```
'Radio' => array(
    'idSong' => '4',
    'name' => 'batman',
    'title' => 'Batman Theme Song'
),
```

why? the type is int in the DB. I need integers correctly displayed in my JSON files

Comment: That is not a CakePHP issue per se, but the PDO classes of PHP do that. There are settings however to prevent that from happening: http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/08/05/all-new-cakephp-tips-summer-2014/#mysql-and-returning-integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there's a straightforward solution, but you could change the model data using [afterfind](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#afterfind)

Something like

```
public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
    foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
        if (isset($val['Radio']['idSong'])) {
            $results[$key]['Radio']['idSong'] = (int)$results[$key]['Radio']['idSong'];
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: I put your code and result is the same : http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/API/moulinette/radio/posts (see debug), in json too http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/API/moulinette/radio/posts.json

Comment: maybe add `var_dump($results)` inside `afterFind` and see how the records look? I assume the afterfind function is in the right model, right?

Comment: Yes, i made a typo mistake :p thks !